# Find limes of multivariable function

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

How to prove that lim (x,y)->(0,0) (((x-y)^2)/(x^2y^2)),   [this limes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAE5D.png)  doesn't exist. By introduction of polar coordinates I got that it is equal to 0, but using wolphram alpha I got it doens't exist. Any help would be great.

--------edit----------

so by polar coordinates I got x=r cos a; y = r sin a;

so lim becomes lim (r)->(0) (((r^2 cos^2a -2 r^2 cos a sin a + r^2 sin a)) /(r^4 cos^2 a sin^2 a))

lim (r)->(0) ((-2 cos a sin a )/(r^2 cos^2 a sin^2 a)) ... = ... inf

Comment: The limit does not exist; share your work for how you got a limit of 0, and we'd be able to help you find your mistake.

Comment: @ndhanson3 I made the edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do it in polar coordinates, then, since $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$, you have$$f(x,y)=f(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)=\frac{\bigl(\csc(\theta)-\sec(\theta)\bigr)^2}{r^2}.$$And you can deduce from this that, indeed, the limit at $(0,0)$ does *not* exist, since $\theta\mapsto\bigl(\csc(\theta)-\sec(\theta)\bigr)^2$ is unbounded. In fact, for each $r>0$ and for each $k>0$, there is some $\theta\in\Bbb R$ such that $\bigl(\csc(\theta)-\sec(\theta)\bigr)^2>kr^2$, and therefore, for such a $\theta$, $f(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)>k$.

So, in this case WolphramAlpha is right. It happens.

Answer (score 0):

I'm introducing $$f(x,y) = \frac{(x-y)^2}{x^2y^2}$$ for your function. Remember that the limit of $f(x,y)$ as $(x,y)\to (0,0)$ exists only if for each sequence $(x_n,y_n)\to (0,0)$ the limit of $f(x_n,y_n)$ exists.

Now consider the sequence $x_n = 1/n$ and $y_n=-1/n$. Then $$f(x_n, y_n) = \frac{(\frac{2}{n})^2}{\frac{1}{n^4}} = 4n^2.$$
Since $x_n\to 0$ and $y_n \to 0$ but the limit as $n\to \infty$ of $f(x_n,y_n)$ does not exist, the limit as $(x,y)\to (0,0)$ of $f(x,y)$ can not exist as well.